# supervisor curl command failing with exit 56 error

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, docker, supervisord

I have this curl cmd I run locally on OSX that completes successfully:

```
 curl -XPOST http://192.168.59.103:9200/inventoryindex

 {"acknowledged":true}
```

BUT when it's run from supervisor in docker it fails...ummmmm

```
 2014-08-16 14:24:38,838 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
 2014-08-16 14:24:39,842 INFO spawned: 'curl' with pid 9
 2014-08-16 14:24:39,843 INFO spawned: 'elasticsearch' with pid 10
 2014-08-16 14:24:39,844 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 11
 2014-08-16 14:24:39,853 INFO exited: curl (exit status 56; not expected)
```

I've tried a couple different variations of the command with same results: Here is the latest version of the supervisor command:

```
 [program:curl]
 command=curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 'http://192.168.59.103:9200/inventoryindex'
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

[UPDATE] So, looking at the info entries I *think* the problem is that supervisor spawns the curl process before elasticsearch has a chance to boot up. I added priority settings to make the curl process spawn last and increased the retry attempts hoping that will mitigate the timing.

```
 [program:curl]
 command=curl -v --header "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 'http://192.168.59.103/:9200/inventoryindex' 
 startretries=5
 priority=1000
```

Also I tried localhost:9200 & 0.0.0.0:9200...zilch. It looks like the spawn order is correct now yet curl is still not completing successfully.

```
 2014-08-16 22:46:50,282 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
 2014-08-16 22:46:51,285 INFO spawned: 'elasticsearch' with pid 10
 2014-08-16 22:46:51,288 INFO spawned: 'rabbitmq-server' with pid 11
 2014-08-16 22:46:51,290 INFO spawned: 'sshd' with pid 12
 2014-08-16 22:46:51,294 INFO spawned: 'curl' with pid 17
 2014-08-16 22:46:51,341 INFO exited: curl (exit status 7; not expected)
```

The retry increase tries again after elastic is running...should be ok now for curl but....zilch.

```
 2014-08-16 22:46:52,340 INFO success: elasticsearch entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
 ...
 2014-08-16 22:46:53,346 INFO spawned: 'curl' with pid 143
 2014-08-16 22:46:53,372 INFO exited: curl (exit status 7; not expected)
```

[UPDATE 2]

1. docker ps (OSX)

   ```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED               STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                          NAMES
    13c872a3ffa7        team1/image1:rabbit   /usr/bin/supervisord   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   22/tcp, 4369/tcp, 5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   elegant_fermi
   ```
2. docker ps (boot2docker)

   ```
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                          NAMES
   13c872a3ffa7        team1/image1:rabbit   /usr/bin/supervisord   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        22/tcp, 4369/tcp, 5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9001->9001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   elegant_fermi
   ```
3. netstat -tunlp ... when I attach to 13c872a3ffa7 from within boot2docker (ssh) there isn't a command prompt available to enter the netstat command so I run the command after ssh'd into boot2docker:

   ```
   netstat: can't scan /proc - are you root?
   Active Internet connections (only servers)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
   tcp        0      0 :::2375                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
   tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
   ```

I ssh'd as docker user (I thought the user had root auth)

Chris...slight change, same result...went from curl to python client. Here's the git link to the code. Thanks!

[UPDATE 3] nsenter installed

1. from within boot2docker:

   a.  get container id via docker ps

   b. get PID

   ```
     PID=`docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' $CONTAINER_ID`
   ```

   c. run nsenter

   ```
    nsenter -t $PID  -m -u -n -i -p -w
    nsenter: cannot open /proc/28160/ns/ipc: Permission denied
   ```

HEAVY SIGH

If I sudo nsenter it switches to root, the previously set vars are wiped and the prompt has no knowledge of the docker command:

```
  nsenter -t 28160 -m -u -n -i -p -w
  nsenter: cannot open /proc/28160/ns/ipc: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 192.168.59.103:9200 points to? Is it running on the same host or VM as the Docker container?

Comment: Add some logging to your `[program:curl]` supervisor config file to get the actual error message: `stdout_logfile=/tmp/logfile.log` and `redirect_stderr=True`.

Comment: @Andy It is the boot2docker ip (it runs the vm)

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel Thanks for the suggestion. The 1st error I see now is "0curl: (52) Empty reply from server" then "0curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer". When I run the command from the local terminal:

Comment: curl -v --header "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST 'http://192.168.59.103:9200/inventoryindex'
* About to connect() to 192.168.59.103 port 9200 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.59.103...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f9a3b00aa00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f9a3b00aa00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 192.168.59.103 (192.168.59.103) port 9200 (#0)
> POST /inventoryindex HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: 192.168.59.103:9200
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/json

Comment: > 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 21
< 
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.59.103 left intact
{"acknowledged":true}

Comment: This is the same command defined in supervisor

Comment: My next stab in the dark, I'm going to put the curl command in a script and try to run that. I think, being that it's not a service supervisor is dealing with it in a way not intended.

Comment: Attach yourself to your container and try to `telnet 192.168.59.103 9200` to prove you can connect to that IP / port from inside your docker container. Also, update your question with the output from 1) `docker ps` on OSX, 2) `docker ps` from inside `boot2docker`, 3) `netstat -tunlp` from inside your running container (use `nsenter` or `docker attach` from insdie your `boot2docker` VM to do this)

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel I added the updates, except for #3...I couldn't telnet in so I ssh'd - should be the same but more "secure", right?

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel I uploaded the code...should help more than my explanations :-)

Comment: I would recommend getting `nsenter` and attaching to your running container to troubleshoot (it turns out docker attach isn't what you're after), you'll have to do this inside your `boot2docker` VM. Once you've downloaded `nsenter`,  you can use this command to attach to your running container: `sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' CONTAINER_ID) -m -u -i -n -p -w`

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel Thanks for the help! I was unsuccessful with nsenter as well. We'll just configure es manually after it boots up. :-(